# Dynamic questionnaire for wix

Tags: integration, velo

I was wondering if anyone of yall knows how to create a dynamic questionnaire for wix (ok to have 3rd party integration if needed). There will be a total of 3 questions with 3 options each
Question 1 : Answer A,B,C
Question 2 : Answer A,B,C
Question 3 : Answer A,B,C

There will be a total of 9 landing pages. Depending on what users answer, they will be lead to 1 of the landing page

Example: qn1 ans:A, qn2 ans:B, qn3 ans:C > leads to 2nd landing page.
qn1 ans:B, qns2 ans:C, qns3 ans:A > leads to 5th landing page

Thanks in advance!

I've tried looking for 3rd party integration but I cant seem to find the right ones that has this function =(